# How to serialize Map field as xml attributes with Jackson mapper

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I have data class

```
class DataItem {

    private String name;
    private Map params;

    // getters, setters

}
```

I easily can serialize it with Jackson as follows

```
<DataItem>
    <name>some name</name>
    <params>
        <p1>one</p1>
        <p2>two</p2>
    </params>
</DataItem>
```

But I want to achieve this output

```
<DataItem>
    <name>some name</name>
    <params p1="one" p2="two">
    </params>
</DataItem>
```

There is an annotation approach (isAttribute = true), but I have dynamic object in *params* field.

Is there a way to make the *param* field be serialized as an element with attributes?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have data from sql query. Next I can build an above object. And then I need to make request to xml-based exchange service. The problem is that the data is not structured and the Map can be different. But exchange protocol makes me to serialize it as attributes

Comment: I can do it without Jackson by simple concatenation, but I'm wondering if there is an easier solution